# Can double quotes("") be used in a string

Tags: c#

I'm looking to add an excel function in a string that has `""` in it.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>"")/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&""))
```

I've tried to use `\"` but no matter how many of them I add together only 1 displays, same happens when I'm trying to use `.Replace` or `((char)34)`.
As Ive already said, I want the output to be "" not ".

Is any way I could get that function as intended?
Im writing this string to a `.csv` file.
Input:
`string suma = @"=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>"")/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&""))";`
Output: Cell A1 `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>)/COUNTIF(B2:D2000`
 Cell B1 `B2:B2000&"))"`
Imput:
                `string suma = "=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>" + ((char)34) + ((char)34) + ")/COUNTIF(B2:D2000" + ((char)44) + "B2:B2000&" + ((char)34) + ((char)34) + "))";`
Output: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>")/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&"))`
Input:                `string suma = "=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>\"\")/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&\"\"))";`
Output: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>")/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&"))`
Input:                    `string suma = "=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>'')/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&''))";
                suma.Replace(@"'",@"&quot;");`
Output: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B2000<>'')/COUNTIF(B2:D2000,B2:B2000&''))`

Comment: Try this link https://exceljet.net/formula/double-quotes-inside-a-formula this will be helpful.

Comment: You need to use `\"` to place a quotation inside a string.

Comment: looks like Ive misstyped there Ive actualy used a "\"".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two double quotes in a row to signify a single double quote within the string literal. If you are using c#, precede the string with `@` to indicate a [verbatim string](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hirendra_singh/verbatim-strings-in-C-Sharp-use-of-symbol-in-string-literals/).

VB

```
s = "The word ""chicken"" has 7 letters."
```

C#

```
var s = @"The word ""chicken"" has 7 letters.";
```

You can also use traditional escaping. Just be sure to use the backslash and not the forward slash.

```
var s = "The word \"chicken\" has 7 letters.";
```

Comment: Ive tryed your code and the output was `The word chicken" has 7 letters."`

Answer (score 2):

Use `\"` to escape the double quotes in C#.